# How to resolve the spacy package installation error

Tags: windows-server-2012, python-3.5

I am using python3.5.2 on windows server. I have tried to install spacy package in my virtual environment on windows. While tring to install spacy with the command using pip, am getting the error **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required**. I have installed that too. But getting the same issue. Please help me solve this issue and install the spacy package

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its asking for Visual Studio C++ Build tools now, at least that was my case. So I installed it and ran vcvarsall.bat from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

After which I could install SpaCy.